# able vs enable ?? which is to be used

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> The telecom sector is the backbone to the Digital India vision and it deserves an *(enabled)* regulatory environment.

Options:
1) enabling
2) enable
3) able

this question came in my exam, and I chose **able**, but the answer given was **enabling**, but I think able is equally correct here, no other context was given in the examination, please help, which do you think is correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude (2) at once, since it is a verb, and the sentence would make no sense. Using either (1) or (2) would result in a grammatical sentence: an 'enabling' regulatory environment would be one which was the opposite of restrictive, whereas an 'able' regulatory environment might be one in which regulation was carried out in an efficient and capable manner. I wonder if you transcribed the question accurately, because all three answers require the indefinite article 'an', since each starts with a vowel. If the original question uses 'a', I am inclined to question the quality of the course material. My own preference would be for (1), since regulatory environments are commonly evaluated to lie somewhere on a continuum between enabling and restrictive.

Comment: Thanks michael ,yes there is "an" ,my mistake. But as "able" also makes sense , should i challenge it ,what do you think?

Comment: Challenge it if you are curious to know the reason. A good student is always curious. If there are two possible grammatical answers, a clue as to which is the preferred one may lie in the course material you have studied, for example types of regulatory environments.

Comment: no clue , it was a lone statement out of nowhere ,no context was given.